# How do I reference a different character in a string while iterating through the string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a script that can take doubled letters (`aa` or `tt`, for instance) and change them to that letter followed by `ː`, the length symbol (`aa` would become `aː`, and `tt` would become `tː`). I want to do this by iterating through the string, and replacing any character in the string that's the same as the last one with a `ː.` How do I do that?

Comment: Strings have a `.replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I iterated through `string` and checked each letter against the previous letter.  If they match it performs the replacement if not it moves on and stores the new previous letter in `previousletter`. Also I used the `.lower()` method to mactch letters even if one is capitalized and one is not.

```
string = "Tthis is a testt of the ddouble letters"

previousletter = string[0]

for letter in string:
    if letter.lower() == previousletter.lower():
       string = string.replace("%s%s" % (previousletter, letter) , "%s:" % (letter))
    previousletter = letter

print(string)
```

And here is the output:

```
t:his is a test: of the d:ouble let:ers
```

I hope this helps and feel free to ask any questions on the code that I used.  Happy programming!